# Swift Protocol inheritance and protocol conformance issue

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

```
protocol BasePresenterProtocol : class {}
protocol DashboardPresenterProtocol : BasePresenterProtocol {}

final class DashboardPresenter {
    weak var view: DashboardPresenterProtocol?

    init() {
        self.view = DashboardViewController()
    }

    func test() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

extension DashboardPresenter: DashboardViewProtocol { }

protocol BaseViewProtocol : class {
    weak var view: BasePresenterProtocol? { get set }
}

protocol DashboardViewProtocol : BaseViewProtocol {
}

class DashboardViewController {
}

extension DashboardViewController: DashboardPresenterProtocol { }
```

In the above code, I get an error at following line

```
extension DashboardPresenter: DashboardViewProtocol { }
```

that, `DashboardPresenter` doesn't confirm to protocol `DashboardViewProtocol`, but I have declared `weak var view: DashboardPresenterProtocol?` in `DashboardPresenter` . Although I have declared

Why am I getting this error ? Please let me know what I am doing wrong in this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot implement a read-write property requirement of type `BasePresenterProtocol?` with a property of type `DashboardPresenterProtocol?`.

Consider what would happen if this *were* possible, and you upcast an instance of `DashboardPresenter` to `DashboardViewProtocol`. You would be able to assign anything that conforms to `BasePresenterProtocol` to a property of type `DashboardPresenterProtocol?` – which would be illegal.

For this reason, a read-write property requirement *has* to be invariant (although it's worth noting that a readable-only property requirement should be able to be covariant – [but this currently isn't supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878)).