# Inhereted protocols conformance

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols

I want to implement next code structure:

```
// Base hierarchy definition
protocol A {}
protocol C {
    var a: A { get set }
}

// Specific definition
protocol B: A {}    
struct TestClass: C {
    var a: B
}
```

1. Protocol `C` requires variable of type `A`.
2. Protocol `B` was inherited from `A`.
3. Class `TestClass` implements `C` protocol by defining variable of type `B` (what should be ok in order of `2`)

But Swift compiler complains that `TestClass` doesn't conform to protocol C because `Candidate has non-matching type 'B'`.

Why Swift compiler takes type `B` as non-matching to type `A`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/40410884/2976878 – a read-write property requirement must be invariant. The protocol `C` says you can assign an *arbitrary* `A` conforming instance to `a`, but `TestClass` says it must be a `B`.

Comment: Yes, its exactly the answer to my question, thanks.