# var defined in protocol doesn't conform to multiple protocol

Tags: swift, class, swift-protocols

I'm struggling with protocols in Swift.
I have defined a protocol like this:

```
protocol AProtocol {
    var property : BProtocol {get set}
}
```

And I would like to conform to `AProtocol` in a class with a property **that also conform to another protocol**. I've tried in these two ways:

```
class AClass: AProtocol {
   var property = BClass()
}
```

and:

```
class AClass: AProtocol {
   var property: BProtocol & MyBClassType = BProtocol()
}
```

but none of them seems to work (BClass itself confirm to BProtocol)
This issue is a bit difficult to explain, I hope it was clear.

Is it a limitation of the Swift language?
Do you know a work around to this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/40410884/2976878 – because `AProperty` is both gettable and settable, allowing a conforming implementation to use any type other than `BProtocol` would be unsound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues: firstly, the property name must match that declared in the protocol, secondly you need to type annotate the variable to be of type `BProtocol` as Hamish explained in the comment.

```
protocol AProtocol {
    var aProperty : BProtocol {get set}
}

protocol BProtocol {}
class BClass: BProtocol {}

class AClass: AProtocol {
    var aProperty: BProtocol = BClass()
}
```

You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names, so I changed `AProperty` to its correct form, `aProperty`.

Comment: Thanks for the answare :) ... the problem is that if I set " aProperty: BProtocol  = BClass() " than I cannot access to the class as BClass type but only as BProtocol without casting it all the time inside AClass

Comment: @AlbertoScampini you can conditionally cast the property to test if its also of type `BClass`, but there's no way to declare it as `BClass` and still conform to `AProtocol`