# Need to satisfy Swift protocol requirement by using a specific subclass of the requirement (or type that conforms to it)

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I have a protocol that I've created (in Swift 4.2), and one of its requirements is a property that is of the same type as the protocol itself.

As an example, I have a protocol defined like so:

```
protocol A {
    var a: A? { get set }
}
```

I have several Models that conform to this protocol:

```
class Model1: A {
    var a: A?
}
```

```
class Model2: A {
    var a: A?
}
```

For one of my models, I need to satisfy the protocol requirement by being more specific for the property defined by variable `a` (i.e. the variable with the protocol type). So for example I may want to implement `Model2` as:

```
class Model2: A {
    var a: Model1?
}
```

In this case since `Model1` conforms to the protocol `A` you would expect this to be able to satisfy the protocol requirement, however I get an error instead:

> Type 'Model2' does not conform to protocol 'A'

Why is this happening, and what can I do to make it work as described above?

**Appendix**

I've modelled the above scenario in an Xcode Playground and here is a screenshot of the error I'm seeing.
[image]

Comment: Does `d` actually need to be settable? If it's not settable, this is straightforward. If it is settable, what would you want `a.d = a` to do if `a` were of type `A`, but implemented as `Model2`?

Comment: For a `{ get set }` requirement [this is unsound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40410884/2976878), as the protocol `A` says you can assign any `A?` value to `var a`, but `Model2`'s `var a` is of type `Model1?`. However for a `{ get }` requirement, this is reasonable [but currently isn't supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878).

Comment: But is easily implemented with a computed property with a different backing ivar. (A technique that's common in ObjC and most OOP languages.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To conform to protocol A, `Model2` would need a member `var a` that allows storing a reference to *anything* conforming to protocol A, not just a reference to a `Model1`. So you can't do this.

Comment: Although this is not a solution, this seems to be the correct answer to the question. A possible workaround is to use a computed property with a backing iVar as suggested above.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with associated types:

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype B: A
    var a: B? { get }
}
```

This would let you declare Model2 with the specificity you wish:

```
class Model2: A {
    var a: Model1?
}
```

But unfortunately, that would mean you could no longer declare variables of type `A`. To fix that, you could use generic models:

```
class Model1<T: A>: A {
    var a: T?
}
```